# Finding the limit of a recursively defined sequence (recurrence relation). Specifically and generally

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, recursion, cauchy-sequences

Whilst reading Goldrei's Classic Set Theory, I have come across a recursively defined sequence

$a_0=0, a_1=1, a_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \right) $

The first few terms of which are:

$0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{8}, \frac{11}{16}, ... $

It is easy to show the successive terms get closer to one another

$ |a_n - a_{n-1} |= | \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}\right) - a_{n-1} |$
$ = \frac{1}{2}|a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|  $

Inducting on the "first difference" gives

$ |a_n - a_{n-1} | = \frac{1}{2}^{n-1}|a_1 - a_0| $
$ = \frac{1}{2}^{n-1} $

So I have shown that the difference between each successive term approaches zero, i.e. the sequence approaches a limit.

How do I find the limit of the recursively defined sequence?

How are these types of problems (recursively defined functions) generally approached? It is:

1. Show the sequence converges
2. ...

Comment: That the differences between successive terms approaches zero does *not* in general prove that the sequence is convergent (consider the harmonic series). – A "related" sequence is considered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260341/compute-lim-limitsn-to-inftya-n-where-a-n2-sqrta-n-a-n1.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: By convergence, I mean that the nth term in the sequence approaches a limit. If the difference between successive terms goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, does not the nth term converge to a value? I realise its sum is not convergent, but what about its nth term?

Comment: @user2321: With $a_n = 1 + \frac 12 + \ldots + \frac 1n$ you have $a_{n+1} - a_n \to 0$, but the sequence $(a_n)$ is not convergent.

Comment: Ah OK, so for that particular sequence (harmonic series 1/n) we don't say it converges to 0? Some reading required for me :)

Comment: This is what I am thinking with the sequence defined by 1/n.   lim n-> infinity (1/n) = 0     Proof let e>0. Then for all n>1/e,  1/n < 1/(1/e) = e.  Therefore limit is 0?

Comment: @user2321: $\frac 1n \to 0$ is correct. But $a_n$ is not convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
a_0=0, a_1=1, a_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \right) \tag 1
$$
is a [Linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) of the order $2$. As explained in that Wikipedia article, the
solution has the form
$$
a_n = C \lambda_1^n + D \lambda_2^n
$$ 
where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are solutions of the "characteristic equation",
in this case
$$
 r^2  = \frac 12 (r + 1) \, , \tag 2
$$
and $C, D$ are determined from the initial values $a_0, a_1$.

$(2)$ has the solutions $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_2 = -\frac 12$,
and together with $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$ it follows that 
$$
a_n = \frac 23 - \frac 23 \bigl(-\frac 12 \bigr)^n \, . \tag 3
$$

---

Another approach is the "generating function". Here is a very brief
sketch of that method: You define formally the power series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n
$$
and use the recurrence relation $(1)$ to conclude that
$$
\bigl(1 - \frac 12 z - \frac 12 z^2 \bigr) f(z) = z \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{1 - \frac 12 z - \frac 12 z^2 }
 = \frac{z}{\bigl( 1-z \bigr)\bigl(1 + \frac z2 \bigr)}
 = \frac 23 \frac{1}{1-z} - \frac 23 \frac{1}{1+\frac z2} \, .
$$
Using the well-known formula for the geometric series, the
explicit formula $(3)$ for the coefficients $a_n$ can be derived.

---

*For this particular sequence*, the limit can be determined easier.
You already observed that
$$
a_n - a_{n-1} = -\frac 12 (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl(a_n - a_{n-1}\bigr) = 0 \, . \tag 4
$$
Another observation (taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260371/42969) is
that 
$$
a_n + \frac 12 a_{n-1} = a_{n-1} + \frac 12  a_{n-2} = \ldots
= a_1 + \frac 12 a_0 = 1 
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl(a_n + \frac 12 a_{n-1} \bigr)= 1 \, . \tag 5
$$

Now combine $(4)$ and $(5)$ to conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty}
a_n = \frac 23 \, $.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution that I think might be insightful for some. You can use your computation to show this sequence is Cauchy also to find the limit:
$$
a_{n}-a_{n-1} = -\frac{1}{2} ( a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) = \cdots = \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n-1}
$$
and now we note that $a_n$ can be written as a telescoping sum
$$
a_n = a_n - a_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n ( a_k - a_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^{k-1}, 
$$
which directly leads to the limit of the sequence being
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^{k} = \frac{1}{1- (-1/2)} = \frac{2}{3}
$$
as this is a geometric series.